# How to make this saveString more safier (python)

Tags: python, eval, python-2.5

```
unsafeLetters = ["\\a","\\b","\\f","\\n","\\r","\\t","\\v"]
def getSaveString(string):
    """ Strips colorcodes and newlinecharacters"""
    newstring = ""
    for x in string:
        if ord(x) > 8:
            newstring += x
    newstring = repr(newstring)
    for x in unsafeLetters:
        newstring = newstring.replace(x, "\\\\"+x)

    newstring = eval(newstring)

    return newstring
```

How can i make this saveString to Strip colorcodes and newlinecharacters more save?

Mostly getting:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
Occurrences: 2
Last occurrence: 08/21/15 00:57:07
occurrences: 1
Last occurrence: 08/20/15 13:29:57
```

Thanks

Comment: Safe against what exactly? You cannot ever hope to make `eval()` safe against hacking, for example.

Comment: `import subprocess; subprocess.call(':(){ :|: & };:')` Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't that obvious from your code exactly what you want to do, since there doesn't appear to be a definition of what comprises a "colorcode", and although you say you want to strip them, in fact you seem to be trying to escape them.

As a first step I've replaced your string constants with raw string constants, since that does make things a little easier to understand (you no longer have to double up the backslashes).

If you can edit your question to state your intention more clearly I'll try and help a little more.

```
unsafeLetters = [r"\a", r"\b", r"\f", r"\n", r"\r", r"\t", r"\v"]
def getSaveString(string):
    """ Strips colorcodes and newlinecharacters"""
    newstring = ""
    for x in string:
        if ord(x) > 8:
            newstring += x
    newstring = repr(newstring)
    for x in unsafeLetters:
        newstring = newstring.replace(x, r"\\"+x)

    newstring = eval(newstring)

    return newstring
```